# Словобразование и синтаксис

Tags: словообразование

Задание (см. ниже): вроде все верно, тогда в чем его суть?

Укажите правильно составленные пропорции с точки зрения словообразовательной модели и морфемного состава.

1 восхищение / восхождение = воспаление / воспитание

2 камень / каменный = сталь / стальной

3 делец / борец = беглец / наглец

4 коренной / тождественный = осенний / обеденный

Может, так: восход - восхождение, камень - каменный, сталь - стальной. корень - коренной, осень - осенний?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве возможного варианта:

В примере 1 разные суффиксы: ЕНИ/ЕНИ И ЕНИ/НИ, тогда **пропорция неверна**.

В остальных случаях **пропорции соблюдены**: 2) мотивирующее слово - суффикс Н; 3) суффикс ЕЦ, мотивация учтена (образование от глагола или от прилагательного); 4) Н/ЕНН = Н/ЕНН, образование от существительного.

Понятие о пропорции можно посмотреть здесь: [УРОКИ ПО М.ПАНОВУ | 1september.ru](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200100204)

Answer (score 1):

Правильным является первый и третий примеры.

Ср.: камень- камен**н**ый, сталь- сталь**н**ой. Корень-корен**н**ой.

Тождество -тождеств**енн**ый, обед -обед**енн**ый.

В паре:делец / борец = беглец / наглец  **последнее слово образовано от прилагательного.**